# Delegate event in vue

Tags: vue.js

Im trying to delegate an avent from one instance to another.

I have a toolbar on the top of the page with a button like this

```
<div id="toolbar">
<button v-on:click="add" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ny</button>
</div>
```

This add event working in this vue instance

```
var toolbarApp = new Vue({
    el: '#toolbar',
    data: {

    },
    methods: {
        add: function (event) {
            alert('lol');
        }
    }
});
```

But now i want to attach this add event to another instance like this

```
var contactApp = new Vue({
    mixins: [toolbarApp],
    el: '#contact',
    data: {
        showGrid: true,
        showForm: false,
        editMode: false
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getContacts();
    },
    methods: {
        getContacts: function () {
            $.getJSON(this.apiGrid, function (data) {
                this.contacts = data;
            }.bind(this));
        },
        add: function (event) {
            alert('hej');
        }
    }
});
```

But i cant attach this because of diffrent instance. Is it any way to do this?
Have also tried with mixedin with no luck.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you are trying to do is not unique, there's even a title for it "Event bus"

```
EventBus = new Vue();

var toolbarApp = new Vue({
    el: '#toolbar',
    data: {

    },
    methods: {
        add: function (event) {
            EventBus.$emit('add-something', this.somevar);
        }
    }
});
```

then in your other instance:

```
var contactApp = new Vue({
    mixins: [toolbarApp],
    el: '#contact',
    data: {
        showGrid: true,
        showForm: false,
        editMode: false
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getContacts();
        EventBus.$on('add-something', function(somevar) {
            // do cool stuff, like this.getContacts...
        });
    },
    methods: {
        getContacts: function () {
            $.getJSON(this.apiGrid, function (data) {
                this.contacts = data;
            }.bind(this));
        },
        add: function (event) {
            alert('hej');
        }
    }
});
```

**Definition:**

Sometimes you need a quick and easy solution to pass data between Vue.js components.

For an application with simple architecture it’s enough to communicate between components using events. For this we can create a quick solution and implement EventBus. EventBus allows us to emit an event in one component and listen for that event in another.

https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860